# Android Device onConfigurationChanged event does not handling orientation

Tags: android, configuration, orientation, landscape, portrait

i have an activity and on startup of the activity i need to change the orientation in lanscape and then later on i want to handle both orientation changes as user rotates device , but it once changes the orientation and later on does not change the orientation. here is my code please help

```
    public class Hls extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hls);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


}



@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Log.v("new orientation", "yes");

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) in onCreate will fix your orientation permanently to landscape and will avoid any change in orientation. That is why your orientation gets fixed and doesn't respond to the rotations.

Here is an alternative you can use :-

1> Create two views in your layout. i.e one for landscape and one for portrait views.Lets say activity_hls_land and activity_hls_port.

2> Use **setContentView(R.layout.activity_hls)** in onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) instead of setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) or setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)

Here is the sample code:-

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
boolean isLaunched=true;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if(isLaunched){
        Toast.makeText(this, "1 st launch " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hls_land);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hls_port);
    }
     if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hls_land );
    } 
    }

}
```

and in the manifest add android:configChanges="orientation" in activity :-

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
          </activity>
```

Sample layout for activity_hls_port :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Sample for landscape mode:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rotation="90">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ok thnx plz tell me that how i would design the layout for landscape i mean what would be difference b/w port and land layouts ..my portlay is 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Hi ! There isn't any difference as such. All you need to do is to create the layout with a landscape orientation.

Comment: how to specify landscape orientation mode in the layout file ?

Comment: It is just the appearance of landscape mode. You need to arrange the views in your layout as if they are in landscape mode.

Comment: I have added sample layouts. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

On this statement

```
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

also in `onCreate(Bundle bundle);`

You called

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

It means that your activity is in landscape/portrait orientation and never rotate again

removing it will trigger the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` again

Comment: I have set this attribute but does not work. The first time when setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); is called in oncreate() , the event onConfigurationChanged is fired , but later on when i rotate the device this event is not fired and configuration  is not being changed.

Comment: yes :( android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" this is what i have added

Comment: i infact want to start the activity in landscape mode and later on change the orientation as user rotates the device ...any idea or solution , please post?

Comment: thank u so much , but can u please tell me how can i achieve my requirement.....
This is okay if i just want to handle the activity runtime orientation changes but i want to set the configuration as landscape through code once the activity is started up and then want to handle the configuration changes on rotating the device . The problem occurs when i change the orientation by calling setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); this sets the orientation to lanscape but then i can not go back to portrait mode even when i rotate device on portrait

Comment: Cheaty way I think.

In your manifest, put android:screenOrientation="portrait"

and then in onCreate(), call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

BTW, If this solves your problem accept it. :)

Comment: hey you said also in onCreate(Bundle bundle);

You called

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
or

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
It means that your activity is in landscape/portrait orientation and never rotate again

removing it will trigger the onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) again....
can u give me the reference of this i want to tell it to my client ?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for late reply..There are other constants of screen orientation.

on official android developer.. this might help you why

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_BEHIND

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your requirement. If you don't mind restarting your activity, you can just skip overriding `onConfigurationChanged`. System will handle Orientation changes for you. In case you don't want it to be restarted on orientation changes, just mention `<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>`, and override `onConfigurationChanged` and call `setContentView()`

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentview(R.layout.activity_hls);
    initializeViews();//here you can initialize all your memberVariables using findViewbyID()
}
```

Comment: This is okay if i just want to handle the activity runtime orientation changes but i want to set the configuration as landscape through code once the activity is started up and then want to handle the configuration changes on rotating the device . The problem occurs when i change the orientation by calling  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);  this sets the orientation to lanscape but then i can not go back to portrait mode even when i rotate device on portrait .